# Vandalism of good answers due to migration from related SE

Tags: discussion

A user seems to object to their (sometimes highly rated and accepted) answers on questions that were migrated to DIY from EE years ago (2016-2018), and is vandalizing these answers (editing them to just read a statement).
The user has already reaped the benefit of substantial reputation gains from these answers, as they're usually well-regarded and solid answers.
And to be clear, the user is not deleting the answers (which would be unfortunate, but perhaps understandable) but just editing them to read a boilerplate "I disagree with this answer being migrated out of EE.SE" message.

Some other active users and I have rolled these answers back to a useful pre-vandalized version, but what should be done about these long-term?
If the user has issues with their answers being migrated along with the question, is there a way to detach them from that user's account?

Example: [I'm replacing my outlets and I have too many hot/neutral wires, what do I do?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105473/im-replacing-my-outlets-and-i-have-too-many-hot-neutral-wires-what-do-i-do)

Answer (score 8):

If a user does not wish to have a post associated with them, [they can request dissociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa).

If a user disagrees with migration, they can flag in the specific case for a moderator to reverse it, or begin a discussion on the local meta site to discuss it generally. However, they should realistically expect this to generate a negative response regarding their actions.

They do not have the right to totally remove content from the site, as it was granted under [a license permitting Stack Exchange to do whatever they want, provided they give attribution when required](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing).

When vandalism occurs, rollbacks are a first-aid response. You should also flag for moderator action if it is observed on multiple posts, or multiple times on the same post.

The user can then be warned or suspended to prevent the actions occurring elsewhere; individual posts can be locked to prevent edit wars.

Comment: Flagging one of the posts for mod action is exactly what I did, and the user has been temporarily suspended. I did suggest that he mark them as community wiki if he wanted to disassociate and/or not receive points for them.